# Configuring Silverlight 5 to test with NUnitLite

Tags: nunit, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to run [this](http://nunit.net/blogs/?p=157) TestPage control but i don't know how to configure assemblies to be test.

My MainPage looks like

```
<UserControl x:Class="RunSilverlightTests.MainPage"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <test:TestPage ></test:TestPage>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and I referenced a silverlight 5 library that contanins a class like:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void foo()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, put all inside the same assembly.